# Stickman Lightwindow & youtube : broken in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, youtube, lightwindow

Stickman's site is down now - looks like he took it off line.  I just found out that IE8 breaks the youtube embed for his lightwindow.  IE8 tried to download the file from the link instead of displaying it.  Anyone have other solutions or a work around for IE8?

Found this page where someone sucked down his How To page before it was taken down.
The YouTube video link shows the issue.
http://edu.cnzz.cn/adcode/demo96/

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed some other issues with IE8 and LightWindow, such as showing an image for the first time, it shows up really small. A second click works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since stickman's solution isn't supported anymore I switched over to another solution.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

works well.

Answer (score 1):

i believe the problem is related to the lack of a filename extension and lightwindow's inability to determine a file type. Adding ".swf" to the end of the youtube URL allows the video to play directly or through lightwindow without error.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a dirty solution for the problem. I replaced the following line

```
$('lightwindow_iframe').setAttribute('src', this.element.href);
```

with this

```
var youtube_content = '<object width="500" height="300"><param name="movie" value="' + this.element.href + '"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="' + this.element.href + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="500" height="300"></embed></object>'
this._writeToIframe(youtube_content);
```

It works, but you can't open other external pages with this fix. Only Youtube embed Video works with this.